# Regarding Equals in java with Objects and Classes

Tags: java, equals

Lets say in java I have a Class A and a Class B which extends A.

Note: classes A and B **don't** have an equals method in them!

I do:

```
A a = new B();
B b = new B();
a.equals(b);
```

It comes out false. I thought when we did equals it dynamically bounded to a and b which would make it true. Or is it because at compile time it looks at a and assumes equals would be equals(A) and since its a B for B b = new B(); it says false? Or am i wrong on both fronts?

Comment: If you don't define an `equals()` method, the default `equals()` method (defined for all `Object`s) is the same as `==`.  Which means it returns `true` only if the objects are the same object (it doesn't look at any data in the object).  You've created two objects, therefore they are not the same.

Comment: Given that `a` and `b` clearly point to different objects, why would expect their comparison via `a.equals(b)` to be `true`?

Comment: If you had defined an `equals()` method for `B`, then `a.equals(b)` would indeed call that method.  So you were almost right--`equals` binds dynamically.  But you were wrong about what happens when you don't define it.

Comment: Alright thanks guys! @ajb i under the impression that the Object equals method had an if statement that asked for InstanceOf but i get it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are not overriding `equals` then it will use `Object`'s method

If you have a look at the source code for Object

```
 @param   obj   the reference object with which to compare.
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
 }
```

Obviously `a` has a different refernce to `b` thus `false`

Comment: Ahhh i got you! i was under the impression for some reason that the Object equals arguments had if(instanceOf) or whatever. Thanks for the clarification all!